# How to set zoom level in JVectorMap

Tags: jquery, svg, jvectormap

I'm using the following code to set the initial zoom level for my jvectormap:

```
$('#world-map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject').setFocus({
    scale: 3
});
```

After I initialise this scale property, the zoom level is set, but the zoom in/out buttons are now blocked. Also in the console I get the following error:

```
Unexpected value scale(2.4000000000000004) translate(undefined, undefined) parsing transform attribute.
```

How can I correctly set the zoom level, and leave the zoom in/out on?

Answer (score 2):

Just googled a bit and i found an object to be attached in the vectorMap instance:

```
$("#world-map").vectorMap({
  focusOn: {
    x: 2,
    y: 2,
    scale: 3
  },
  // ...
});
```

Here the x and y properties are needed to set the position while scale is the scale factor.. very intuitive at all